# Is there any guide for making KeystoneJS to work with PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, content-management-system, keystonejs

KeystoneJS looks like a great CMS framework, however it claims to work with MongoDB only.

Do you think it's technically feasible to make KeystoneJS support PostgreSQL with the least effort?

Is there any guide related to it?